# Button selection: Angular

Tags: angular

Is it possible to make multiple selections for a button, something like a checkbox where you could choose multiple options. In my case, I would want to select two buttons then use the ids from the selected the button and transfer their information over to another page. Any insights or solutions on how to go about doing that is much appreciated. Below is an image I knocked up with  functionality I would want to have. On the next page It would display names of titles selected like "testing and mocking metric" I guess that's not important. I assume the route/url would have both id numbers in it. Something to the effect of http://localhost:4200/compare/1&3. Also below are snippets of my program which includes my html file, .ts file and app-routing.module.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Domain } from '../library';
import { DOMAIN } from '../domain-names';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-compare',
  templateUrl: './compare.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./compare.component.css']
})
export class CompareComponent implements OnInit {


  domain = DOMAIN;

  selectedDomain: Domain;

  onSelect(dom: Domain): void {
    this.selectedDomain = dom;
  }



  constructor( ) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

```css
ul {
   padding: 0;
   width: 1200px;
   margin: 20px auto;
 }

li{
   display: inline;
}

h2{
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-info{
  margin: 6px;
}

.button-row{
  margin: auto;;
}

.btn-outline-light {
    padding: 6px;
    border: 4px solid #eee;
    box-shadow: #555 1px 1px 8px 1px;
    height: 160px;
    width: 200px;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<h2> Visualized Metrics By Domain </h2>
<div class="button-row">
  <ul id="thumbnailslist">
    <li *ngFor="let dom of domain" (click)="onSelect(dom)">
      <a routerLink="/domain/{{dom.id}}">
        <button type="button" class="btn-outline-light">{{dom.catergory}}</button>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
import { NgModule }  from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CompareComponent } from './compare/compare.component';
import {  DomainCompareComponent } from './domaincompare/domaincompare.component';



const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
 
  { path: 'compare', component: CompareComponent },
  { path: 'compare/:id', component: DomainCompareComponent}

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes
  ) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Change the behavior of button css by the status of action

Comment: And store the selected buttons' id in an array in order to not have to evaluate css for checked buttons again.

Comment: On button click event handler, set the css class for all clicked buttons and using the event argument passed to the click handler, get the button Id or any other attribute and store in some array. You can write couple of functions to add/remove selected button Ids from array as well and once navigated anywhere else, just read the array.

Comment: @Usman not sure what you mean by set the css class for all clicked buttons and using the event argument passed to the click handler, get the button Id or any other attribute and store in some array.

Comment: as I can see in your code you have used `routerLink` for `a` that means as soon as you click on it it will redirect to other page. So how you will be able to select more than 1 item at a time?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to add the new functionality, this code was based on something else I was doing. That's why i'm not sure how to approach my following question @AnshumanJaiswal

Comment: @pennyBoy I would suggest to create a stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com) of your code. It would be easier for others to understand your problem correctly. You can use dummy `json` for domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use buttons, since you probably don't want any immediate action. And they are harder to style anyway.

```
<li *ngFor="let dom of domain" (click)="onSelect(dom)">
    <div [style.background-color]="isSelected(domain) ? 'red' : 'white'" (click)="toggleDomain(domain)"></div>
</li>
```

And in component:

```
selectedDomains: Domain[];

toggleDomain(domain: Domain) {
    if(this.selectedDomains.includes(domain)) {
        this.selectedDomains.splice(this.selectedDomains.indexOf(domain), 1);
    } else {
        this.selectedDomains.push(domain);
    }
}

isSelected(domain: Domain) {
    return this.selectedDomains.includes(domain);
}
```

Then you have an array of selected domains, which you can easily send to the other component.

Next page component will probably need to receive the data as input:

```
<next-page-selector [domains]="domains"></next-page-selector>

@Input() domains: Domain[];
```

So you can show selected component names. Next component template:

```
<span *ngFor="let domain of domains">{{domain.name}}</span>
```

Comment: I think this might, can we continue you this discussion in a chat?

Comment: Sure, ask away, but I'm going to work in a couple of minutes, so I will be able to answer in an hour or so.

Comment: Ok well I thought knew how to make a chat but I don't. Anyways, when implement this into my code I get these errors like "Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'Domain'" do I have to import something?

Comment: No, you didn't change your `selectedDomain: Domain` to `selectedDomains: Domain[]`, it has to be an array.

Comment: Oh ok.. So based on this implementation, I would not have to incorporate any routing into this?

Comment: I don't think so. You can just show your `next component` as a child of the `compare component`, as I've showed in the answer. You could also show the info in another component. for which you could add a button with routing and send the data like so: `<a [router-link]="['./route'],{data:selectedItems}">Go to next component</a>`

Comment: Ok thank you make sense now. But last thing, I got this error "annot read property 'includes' of undefined
    at CompareComponent.isSelected" i have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: My bad, you have to initialize your array for it to not be undefined. So instead of `selectedItems: Domain[]` initialize it as an empty array: `selectedItems: Domain[] = []`;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168267/discussion-between-ritaj-and-pennyboy).